# Login with temp password or password to login in L5

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.1

I'm using Laravel 5.1 to build back-end system with RESTFUl resources which will be consumed by some mobile applications.

**Forgot Password Story**

if someone forgot password then the server has to send an email with the temporary password to his registered email. From the next time on words server has to authenticate the user either with **temp password** or with the **password**

Can someone guide me how to do this

Comment: is this your question? "From the next time on words server has to authenticate the user either with temp password or with the password" Are  you asking for the password that can be used or how to implement this?

Comment: @Digitlimit sry for my bad english. asking how to implement a authentication system that will allow anyone ie either pwd or temp pwd.

Comment: You can modify the PasswordController, however this not a good idea. Why don't you send a password reset link to email rather than resetting user password. How do you wish to create a temporal password

Comment: @Digitlimit that's true for the web applications. but in my case requests are coming from mobile apps. And i'm generating the temporal password with a 8 character random string, sending the mail with the generated string and bcrypting the string and saving it in to the 'rand_password' column in the user table.  Now system has to allow the user to login with the combination of email, password or email, temp_password

Comment: Okay. I think i understand better. user can login with email and password or email and temp_password right? Maybe when they login with temp_password they should be prompted to change password, after which temp_password would no longer be valid

Comment: yeah exactly, user can login with email and password or email and temp_password. Need to allow them to login without prompting to change password. Even temp_password will exists forever

Comment: What you have tried so far ? Can you show the code that you have so far ?

Comment: My plan is like follows      `if (Auth::attempt(['email' =>        \Request::get('email'), '
                              password' => bcrypt(\Request::get('password')])) 
               return true;
          elseif($user = User::where('temp_password', bcrypt(\Request::get('password'))->first()){
               Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
                return true;
            }
          }else
            return false; `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your `PasswordController` located in `app\http\controllers\auth`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

use App\Models\User; //yours is probably App\User;
use Mail, Hash;

class PasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */
    use ResetsPasswords;
    /**
     * Create a new password controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }


    public function postEmail(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, ['email' => 'required|email']);

        $email = $request->get('email');

        if(!$user = User::where('email', $email)->first()) return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Email does not exists');

        //create temporal password
        $temp_password = str_random(8); //generates random 8 characters long string

        //hash password and save in database
        //I assume you have `temp_password` in your users column
        $user->temp_password = Hash::make($temp_password);
        $user->save();

        //data to be used in mail
        $data['subject']            = 'Password Reminder'; //$this->getEmailSubject();
        $data['email']              = $email;
        $data['temp_password']      = $temp_password;

        //send mail to user
        Mail::send('emails.password_reminder', $data, function($message) use ($data)
        {
            $message->from('no-reply@site.com', $data['subject']);
            $message->subject($data['subject']);
            $message->to($data['email']);
        });

    }
}
```

Then in `resource/views/emails` create `password_reminder.blade.php`

```
Your temporal password is {{$temp_password}}
NB:Someone requested a password reminder, if you are not the one kindly ignore
```

**For User Authentication**

try - (not tested)

```
$email = \Request::get('email'); 
$password = \Request::get('password'); 

if (Auth::attempt(['email' =>$email, 'password' => $password])){ 
    return true; 
}elseif(Auth::attempt(['email' =>$email, 'temp_password' => $password])){ 
    return true; 
}else{ 
   return false; 
}
```

or try this

```
$email = \Request::get('email'); 
$password = \Request::get('password'); 
$user = User::where('email',$email)->first(); 

if(!$user) return false;

if (Auth::attempt(['email' =>$email, 'password' => $password])){ 
    return true; 
}elseif(\Hash::check($password, $user->temp_password)){ 
    Auth::loginUsingId($user->id); return true; 
}else{ 
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: FYI  Generating temporal password, sending email with temporal password and saving it in DB is done. My only concern is while user is trying to login we don't know weather he is using temp_password or password. see my code example as a reply for Sulthan Allaudeen. Please correct me if i'm wrong

Comment: @siva try `$email = \Request::get('email');
        $password = \Request::get('password');
        
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' =>$email, 'password' => $password])){
            return true;
        }elseif(Auth::attempt(['email' =>$email, 'temp_password' => $password])){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }`

Comment: or try this `$email = \Request::get('email');
        $password = \Request::get('password');

        $user = User::where('email',$email)->first();

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' =>$email, 'password' => $password])){
            return true;
        }elseif(\Hash::check($password, $user->temp_password)){
            Auth::loginUsingId($user->id); return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }`

Comment: Thanks alot for your quick response. I checked and juss the above one is working fine. Now in my system user can be able to login using temp_password or with password

Comment: good. Please if I solved your problem kindly accept my answer